# Independent and dependent variables in Repeated Measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I am working on a study where I have a sample of 86 students. I have tests for 5th grade, 6th grade, 7th grade, and 8th grade. I think I can run a Repeated Measures ANOVA since I have observations for 4 different occasions.

However, I am unsure what my independent and dependent variables are in this set up.

Comment: Could you tell us what your variables are? I could probably help you sort out which are independent and dependent!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are having a hard time due to your data structure. Based on your description i think you have data in the "wide" format, like this:

```
Student-ID  5th     6th     7th     8th      Sex
1           result1 result2 result3 result4  male
2           result5 result6 ...              female
```

(result1, result2,... being the test scores)

Your dependent and independent variables will become clear if you restructure your data to "long" format:

```
Student-ID Sex    Grade TestResult
1          male   5th   result1
1          male   6th   result2
1          male   7th   result3
1          male   8th   result4
2          female 5th   result5
2          female 6th   result6
...
```

Now the dependent variable is the TestResults, while the independent variables (in my example) are sex and grade.

If thats not clarifying your problem, do as Kyle says.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the Grade variable as IV

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer. Of course **grade** might be an IV or a random effect, too. Think it depends on the aim of the study.